# How to get live data from a website in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I want to get the price of an item from AliExpress in Excel.

For example, [this item](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32810872544.html?pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22:%2212000026955302076%22%7D). I modified the URL to get the specific product variant using [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162486/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-product-variant-on-an-ali-express-product-page/162490#162490?newreg=2c1c6cefe94c4c8493b94327a704f79a).

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/kplttg/pulling_live_data_prices_from_a_website_like/) to get the name and price of the product. Here is the code:

```
Sub hello()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim name As String
Dim price1, price2, price3 As Long

' Website to go to.
website = Range("URL").Value

If InStr(website, "https://") <= 0 Then
' If website = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
name = html.getElementsByClassName("title--wrap--Ms9Zv4A").Item(0).innerText
price1 = html.getElementsByClassName("es--wrap--erdmPRe").Item(0).innerText
price2 = html.getElementsByClassName("es--wrap--erdmPRe").Item(1).innerText
price3 = html.getElementsByClassName("es--wrap--erdmPRe").Item(2).innerText

' Output the price into a message box.
' MsgBox price

Range("Name").Value = name
Range("Price1").Value = price1 * 1
Range("Price2").Value = price2 * 1
Range("Price3").Value = price3 * 1
End Sub
```

I have cells with the following names:

```
Name, Price1, Price2, Price3, URL
```

But whenever I run this macro, I get an error on the line

```
name = html.getElementsByClassName("title--wrap--Ms9Zv4A").Item(0).innerText
```

The error says:

```
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

**Edit:**

I put *response* into a cell, then copied it into a note document, then searched using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, but it could not find it. I looked closer at the html, and I noticed that the first bit of text matches with the website (when I use the inspect tool with my browser), but the rest does not match and a lot of characters are missing. What's causing this?

**Edit:**

I recreated this in C# WinForms and I there's a lot more html in the generated file than in the VB.net version. Upon closer inspection of the html, it turns out all the information is there, it's just in a different format. I'm not sure why, but I can work with it.

Comment: Do you have `option explicit` set anywhere in your code? Maybe in global declarations?

Comment: I did not. I just tried adding it to the very top of the code, and I still get the same error

Comment: You need to find if you have it elsewhere, not add it again. `Option Explicit` tells the run-time compiler that all variables must be declared. You can omit the flag, meaning you don't have to declare all your variables. Your error is because you haven't declared a variable, so removing `option explicit` will suppress the error.

Comment: It's not in my Macro, is there somewhere else I need to look?

Comment: When I go to Tools > Options, "Require Variable Declaration" is disabled.

Comment: Yes, perform a search for `option explicit` across the entire solution.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried `Crtl + F` and selected `current project`, but that had no results.

Comment: I don't have any other macros or code I wrote. I think the issue is something else